# How can I create a ParseQuery for a field that is either undefined, or contains a particular value?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to construct a `ParseQuery` for some data, and I'm looking to return objects that have a particular field either undefined, or with a particular value. Is this possible, or do I have to find all of the values I *don't* want it to have, and use `whereNotEqualTo` or `whereNotContainedIn` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Compound Queries](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries-compound)

`ParseTest` is class with `Value` field. It's `String` type. Table contains next rows

- '2'
- '1'
- undefined

  ```
  ParseQuery<TestParse> queryUndefined = ParseQuery.getQuery(TestParse.class);
  queryUndefined.whereDoesNotExist("Value");
  ParseQuery<TestParse> queryParticualValue = ParseQuery.getQuery(TestParse.class);
  queryParticualValue.whereEqualTo("Value", "2");
  ParseQuery<TestParse> orQuery = ParseQuery.or(Arrays.asList(queryUndefined, queryParticualValue));
  List<TestParse> list = orQuery.find();
  ```

Result of query will contain '2' and undefined values.